# Postgresql schema povider

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, codesmith, .nettiers

I have a ASP.NET project that is used MS SQL db. DB access code is generated using CodeSmith .netTiers. Now, project will be merged with another and should use PostgreSQL db. I am looking for PostgreSQL Schema Provider for CodeSmith. But found only next topic on CodeSmith comunity: http://community.codesmithtools.com/nettiers/f/16/t/4463.aspx?PageIndex=2

Can be used PostgreSQL with .netTiers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be used with .netTiers but there may be some work needed. I'll try and get his patches. Please use the PostgreSQLSchemaProvider that ships with [CodeSmith Generator](http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/generator). We have recently rewrote the entire provider and have been doing a lot of testing on it. Please contact support for a nightly build of CodeSmith Generator which contains two extra PostgreSQLSchemaProvider bug fixes. Please let us know if you have any [questions](http://community.codesmithtools.com/nettiers/f/16.aspx).

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski